# Is there anything in middle-earth that still exists today?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In J.R.R Tolkien's, The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring. Frodo sings a song at Bree, that is supposed to be a precursor to the nursery rhyme, 'Hey Diddle Diddle'.

Is there anything else that exists in Tolkien's Middle-Earth work that is designed to be an earlier version of something that exists/existed?

(For example, are there certain cities or land marks that still exist today?)

Comment: in the Hobbit we are told that Hobbits still exist in modern times (or at least the time of the narrator, which one assumes to be Tolkien)

Comment: Welcome back. This is actually quite difficult to answer. I think the only thing is as @NKCampbell said, the Hobbits

Comment: If memory serves, in "The Hobbit" we were told that a Hobbit invented the game of golf when, in a battle, he chopped off the head of a goblin-king named Golfimbul, and it flew through the air and landed in a hole.

Comment: Well, evil certainly still exists.